# Unable to connect to xampp server over local wifi network

Tags: networking, xampp, wifi

I have deployed xampp over machine A with ip xxx:XXX:yy:y but I am not able to get servers index.html over machine B with url xxx:XXX:yy:y/index.html. Both A & B are on the same Wifi network. Xampp Server is running on windows system. Why is so ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the same port for example: 192.168.0.0/8181